# az ad app update does not work for groupMembershipClaims

Tags: azure, azure-cli

As resulted from case [REG:119091922002157] I learned that "az ad app update" is case sensitive for groupMembershipClaims

It returns "None" and you should update the value with "none" (or the other way around - I forgot)

Please update documentation or even better, make it case-insensitive.

Comment: this is not a azure cli issue tracker, go create an issue [there](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that suggestion! I'll work on cascading this to the Azure CLI Engineering Team and let you know as I have an update on the request. Meanwhile, I'd suggest you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues) as well if you're anticipating a quicker response.

**UPDATE:**
When using

```
az ad app update --id xxxxxxx --set groupMembershipClaims=None
```

CLI is parsing `None` as a Python expression thus removing groupMembershipClaims from the update parameters. (see [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/ffebdf45c957483745431ce0e2ed6d85242266af/src/azure-cli-core/azure/cli/core/util.py#L266) for implementation details)

The solution is to use **--force-string** arg to parse None as a string literal:

```
ad app update --id xxxxxxx --set groupMembershipClaims=None --force-string
```

Please check if this helps.

Comment: @ibruynin Updated my response with additional details. Please check.